# Why ANTLR test rig gives no output and just skip to the end?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a C source file containing about 1200 lines of code.

I use the ANTLR test rig to parse it with the [ANTLR C grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/c).

At first, it gave me a few trivial errors for unrecognized tokens. It's easy to fix it in the C source code. But after I fixed all of them, the ANTLR test rig just finished without any result. And no error. Only this with the `-tokens` switch:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
[@0,40604:40603='<EOF>',<EOF>,1238:0]
```

Then I tried `-gui`, it only gave me a blank image:

[image]

So, what could be wrong? Is it an issue of the ANTLR test rig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the root cause is below macro definition:

```
#define SET_BOOT_OPTION_SUPPORT_KEY_COUNT(a, c) {  \
      (a) = ((a) & ~EFI_BOOT_OPTION_SUPPORT_COUNT) | (((c) << LowBitSet32 (EFI_BOOT_OPTION_SUPPORT_COUNT)) & EFI_BOOT_OPTION_SUPPORT_COUNT); \
      }
```

After I removed it, the test rig can output result.

I had a similar issue before that ANTLR cannot recognize `#include`. In that case, ANTLR reports error for that. But in this case, no error is reported.

I think I have to apply the C grammar **after** finishing the preprocessing.

Comment: Since the preprocessor language is line oriented, it makes a lot of sense to handle it first with a simple line reader, before passing the actual code to a parser (and its name somehow hints at that approach ;-) ). I have written a [Windows RC file parser](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/java/windows-resource-file-parser-and-converter). These files are very much like C header files, hence there's preprocessing, macro expansion, stringinzing etc. included. Use that as an inspiration.

Comment: So, all the statement starting with a `#` behave as a single line?

Comment: Yes, always. That's how the preprocessor is designed. Be aware of line continuation (a backslash before the line break), which should make the preprocessor to concatenate the current and the next line.